# Clarification in a proof that free modules are flat

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, free-modules

In section 10.5 of Dummit and Foote, we are given a proof that free modules are flat that goes like this:

1). Finitely generated free modules are flat (easy)

2). Suppose now that $F$ is an arbitrary free $R$-module, and $L$ and $M$ are $R$-modules with $\psi: L \to M$ injective. We want to show that $1 \otimes \psi: F \otimes L \to F \otimes M$ is injective.

3). This part contains the step I am confused about:

Suppose that some $\sum (f_i \otimes l_i)$ is sent to $0$ by $1 \otimes \psi$. Then $\sum (f_i \otimes \psi(l_i))$ is $0$ in $F \otimes M$, so $\sum(f_i, \psi(l_i))$ can be written as a finite sum of generators for the relations that give $F \otimes M$ as a quotient of the free ($\mathbb{Z}$) module on $F \times M$.

After this, I am lost as the proof goes "because the sum is finite, all of the first coordinates of the resulting equation lie in some finitely generated free submodule $F'$ of $F$ ". How do we get this? Can someone help me write it down more explicitly?

4). Because of 1). we can conclude that $\sum (f_i \otimes l_i)$ must be $0$ in $F' \otimes L$ hence also $0$ in $F \otimes L$

Comment: I think it is conceptually simpler to first *set up* the tensor in a better form instead of making it a sum of random tensors first and only later making adjustments. See the proof of Theorem 3.2 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf.

Comment: take the submodule of $F$ spanned by the summands.

Comment: @hunter do you mean the $f_i$? why would that necessarily generated a free module?

Comment: @KCd Thank you for the reference! However, I asked this question because in a later exercise we are asked to mimic this proof to show that $A$ is flat if $A \otimes -$ preserves injective maps $L \to M$ where $L$ is finitely generated. In this case, am I correct in thinking we cannot directly mimic Theorem 3.2 since we can't uniquely "set up" the tensors?

Comment: Choose a basis $B$ for the free module $F$. Express each $f_i$ as a linear combination of elements of $B$. Since there are only finitely many $f_i$'s and since a linear combination involves only finitely many elements of $B$, these linear combinations involve only a finite subset $B'$ of $B$ altogether. The $F'$ you want is the submodule generated freely by $B'$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you! I think I understand this now. My last point of confusion now is, why does the proof given in Dummit and Foote speak of the free module on $F \times M$ at all? It doesn't seem relevant..

Comment: @student_in_training It seems they defined the tensor product $F\otimes M$ as a certain quotient of the free module on $F\times M$, and so their proofs about tensor products will refer back to the free modules. (I agree with KCd that this is not the best way to define $\otimes$.)

Comment: To answer my own last question, I assume that D&F talk about the relations on the free module on $F \times M$ to justify that being $0$ in $F' \otimes M$ means you are also $0$ in $F \otimes M$

Comment: I asked a similar question [here in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407417/proving-that-free-modules-are-flat-without-appealing-projective-modules) a while ago that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Tihs can be done a lot easier, free $R-$modules are of the form $R[S]$, (freely generated module on elements of a set $S$, not polynomial algebra) we also know that the tensor product commutes with direct sums $$(\bigoplus_i M_i) \otimes_R A = \bigoplus_i (M_i \otimes_R A)$$

So tensoring with a free module $F = R[S]$ is the same as applying the functor $\bigoplus_{i \in S}$ since $R[S] = \bigoplus_{i \in S} R$ and $R \otimes_R M = M$.

Then if

$$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$$

is exact we show that

$$0 \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in S} A \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in S} B \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in S} C \rightarrow 0$$

is also exact pretty easily hence proving that free modules are also flat.